# SQL - inner join sum product

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

I have 2 tables "invoice" and "invoice_product".

In the first table I have columns like (id, invoice_date, buyer_name, total_price ...)
I the second table I have products connected with buyer invoice (id, invoice_id, product_id, product_price, product_unit, amout).
The same product can have different units (for example orange - sell bags and weight)
Now I want to display something likie this

Input data ivnoive_product:

```
Product | unit | price | buyer  | invoice_id
Orange  | 1kg  | 5.50$ | Alfred | 55
Orange  | 2bags| 25$   | Alfred | 79
Orange  | 1kg  | 5.50$ | Sam    | 16
Banana  | 2kg  | 2.50$ | Alfred | 55
```

a) sum client price
Result display table with client sum:

```
Buyer | Sum price  | 
Alfred| 33$        | (include orange and banana)
Sam   | 5.50$      |
```

a2) How can I select if i have where (with id_product == orange product)
...where id_product = 5

```
Buyer  | Sum price
Alfred | 30.5$ (without banana price)
```

b) sum product price
Result display:

```
Product | Units      | Sum price
Orange  | 2kg, 2bags | 36.00$
Banana  | 2kg        | 2.50$
```

I don't want that my select sql query duplicate products and buyers like this:

```
Orange | 2kg | 11$
Orange | 2bags | 25$
Banana | 2kg | 2.5$
```

I want to use pagination (Zend framework) where in the first page it shows only ten first row returned by query. (If I have duplicate products, then I have less row in the first page)

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Sum client price:

```
select buyer, sum(price ) 
from invoice_product
group by buyer
```